# testing app settings retrieval in C# unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am somewhat of a newbie to unit testing. I have a solution with an MVC5 project and its associated unit test project. I have 4 other class libraries in that solution and added a unit test project to encapsulate all the tests for those other class libraries.

Question #1. Is the above the right approach or does each library need its own unit test?

I created a unit test, to essentially test if the unit tests worked!

```
public class TestAppSettingsRetrieval
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

        var emailProvider = Services.Helpers.ServicesAppSettings.EmailSettings.EmailProvider;
        Assert.AreEqual(emailProvider, "gmail.com");
    }
}
```

This pulls (or is supposed to pull) the EmailProvider app setting from the app.config file in my services project.

Here are the appsettings config and the ServicesAppSettings class.

```
 public static class ServicesAppSettings
{
    public static class SmsSettings
    {
        public static string SmsProvider => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmsProvider"];
        public static string SmsAccountIdentifier => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmsAccountIdentifier"];
        public static string SmsPassword => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmsAccountPassword"];
        public static string SmsFromPhone => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmsFromPhone"];
    }

    public static class EmailSettings
    {
        public static string EmailProvider => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailProvider"];
        public static string EmailProviderHost => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailProviderHost"];
        public static string EmailAccount => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailAccount"];
        public static string EmailAccountPassword => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailAccountPassword"];
    }
}


<appSettings>
    <!--email settings-->
    <add key="EmailProvider" value="gmail.com" />
    <add key="EmailProviderHost" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <add key="EmailAccount" value="**" />
    <add key="EmailAccountPassword" value="**" />
</appSettings>
```

The test always fails as the value returned is null.
Question #2 Can I not retrieve from the app.config from another project in unit tests?

Comment: I think the path to the app.config file is determined by which project is *entry point* - this will of course not be the same when you run a test project as when you run the actual application. Try copying the app.config file from your service project to the test project, and see if that works. If it does, you might want to add a pre-build action to ensure that you always have a version which is up-to-date.

Comment: yes, putting the app config in the test project works, but that defeats the purpose of being able to test from one unit test project to the 4 others.

Comment: I think what you are trying to test is - *"The method can read the value of `EmailProvider` correctly from the `.config` file"*. So, you should rather test the *functionality* than *values*. Now, if that method can read the values correctly from your Unit Test's config file, that should be good enough.

Comment: @Arghya C  you are right. And it does work correctly with app.config in the test project

Comment: Question #1. There is no 'right' approach, use what is best for your project/solution. As for the rest, as previous commenters have mentioned, the app settings come from the config file located at the entry point of the execution. So basically, putting those settings into the config file for the test project sound right to me.